# There is already an object named '#xxxx' in the database

Tags: sql-server, ssms, temp-tables

I'm dropping/creating a temp table many times in a single script

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#uDims') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #uDims

select * into #uDims from table1

.... do something else 

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#uDims') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #uDims

select * into #uDims from table2 -- >> I get error here

.... do something else 

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#uDims') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #uDims

select * into #uDims from table3  -- >> and here

.... do something else
```

when trying to run the script, I get

```
There is already an object named '#uDims' in the database.
```

on the second and third "select into..."

That is obviously a compile time error. If I run the script section by section, every thing will work well.

There are many workaround for this issue, but I want to know why SSMS is upset on that.

Comment: This is a stored procedure, so there is no GO.

Comment: [This answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/128866/361) in dba.se explains the issue correctly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't create the same temp table more than once inside a stored procedure.

Per the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979(v=sql.110).aspx) (in the Remarks section),

> If more than one temporary table is created inside a single stored
>   procedure or batch, they must have different names.

So, you either have to use different temp table names or you have to do this outside a stored procedure and use `GO`.

Comment: While that's true, that's not what's at play here.

Example : say you imported data and wanted to rename it to a temp table, then check if it exists, and finally give Microsoft's very special intellisense needed hints. So you do IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.imported') IS NOT NULL BEGIN SELECT * INTO ##temptable FROM imported DROP TABLE tempdb.dbo.imported END IF OBJECT_ID('##temptable') IS NULL RAISERROR('errmsg', 20, -1) WITH LOG CREATE TABLE... In this case you have only created the table once, at most, but the linter still prevents execution incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Ivan Starostin is correct. I test on my SQL this TSQL and it works fine.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#uDims') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #uDims
select top 10 *  into #uDims from tblS
go 
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#uDims') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #uDims
select top 10 * into #uDims from Waters
```

without the go I get the same error as you(FLICKER).

Comment: but op said that this is inside a stored procedure, so s/he can't use `GO`

Comment: Right, as i mentioned, it is a stored procedure. Logically and technically, nothing is wrong with my script. it is just SSMS issue. SSMS tries to be smart but it is not enough as it doesn't see I have dropped the table before "select into..."

Comment: @Flicker, do you need to know why you are getting error or how to circumvent it?

Comment: @IvanStarostin Last sentence `but I want to know why SSMS is upset on that.`

Comment: Because `DDL without GO`. Same as attempting to update just created column in same batch.

Comment: As Mentioned there are workarounds. I just want to make sure is this SSMS issue or is there any way, I help SSMS to not bug me on that, or any other suggestions.

Comment: @IvanStarostin, I don't know what is wrong with having DDL w/o GO? I have many scripts that I create temp or physical tables. creating index on them/ dropping them/ altering index and ...., all in one stored procedure. Wy you are mentioning that DDL has to have GO?

Comment: @IvanStarostin That's **not** the issue, as you could do this if you were using actual tables instead of temporary ones. I posted a comment to a post in dba.se where it explains this situation

Comment: @Lamak that was a surprise for me that server allows this for real tables. Most of schema-changing DDL commands require separate batch. I really thought temp tables issue is related to this.

Answer (score 1):

For a script, as others have said using `GO` is the fix.

However, if this is actually code in a stored procedure, you’ve got a different problem. It’s not SSMS that doesn’t like the syntax, it’s the SQL compiler. It sees and chokes on those three `INSERT… INTO…` statements, and is not clever enough to realize that you are dropping the table between creation statements. (Even if you take out the `IF` statements, you still get the problem.)

The fix is to use different temp table names. (A fringe benefit, since the temp table are based on three different tables, this will help make it clearer that the table structures are different.) If you are worried about excess space in memory, you can still drop each temp table once you’re done with it.